# Error occurred while migrating a web application from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, migration, iis-10

We have a legacy .Net web application which was created using Visual studio 2008 is hosted in IIS is running fine in old server having .Net framework 2.0 in it.  We are in process of migrating application to new server having .Net 4.7 framework. Unfortunately we don't have latest source code of the application. So, i have copied the published folder from the old server and deployed on the new server.

But while browsing the deployed legacy application on the new server i am getting below screen [image]

There is no logging mechanism in the application to see what is missing in the new server for this application. I have compared security and permission for published folder in old and new server and they are merely same.

Is there any way to identity the actual error and make that published folder working in new server because same published code is working fine in old server.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: The call stack is clear enough, so you just need to check the source code of the web app, or decompile its assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is version of dotnet.Check installed version and comparasion.Suddenly this type of errors revelant versions problem.

Comment: Yes we know that is due to version change but what need to make it working on new server ??

Comment: there is a file in netframework folder.
edit machine.config and delete this "</DbProviderFactories>"

Comment: Which </DbProviderFactories> you are talking about ?